# How to filter records in Nested Active Scaffold records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using active scaffold to list my users. The users has many published posts and unpublished posts. I  need two links in my users active scaffold table "Published posts" and "unpublished posts". When clicked on Published posts, it should display all the published posts fields under the user record and the same for un published posts.

I used nested to list all the posts for the user in the active scaffold but I am not able to filter the posts records based on the column "publised?" .. how can i do it ?

please help

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

...

has_many :published_reports, :class_name => "Report", :conditions => "reports.published = 1"
has_many :unpublished_reports, :class_name => "Report", :conditions => "reports.published = 0"

...

end

class UsersController < ApplicationController

active_scaffold :users do |config|
    ...

    config.actions = [:nested, :list, :show, :field_search]
    config.nested.add_link("Published", :published_reports)
    config.nested.add_link("Unpublished", :unpublished_reports)
    ...

end

end
```